# variadic template of template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

To put it simple, let's consider 2 stages.

1. I define variadic structs `variadic1`, `variadic2`, ... and template template `applyTo_double_float`
   like so

   ```
   template<class...T> 
   struct variadic1;

   template<class...T>
   struct variadic2;

   template<template<typename...> class Templ>
   struct applyTo_double_float
   {
       typedef Templ<double, float> type;
   };
   ```

   Having this, the result of e.g. `applyTo_double_float<variadic1>::type` is `variadic1<double,float>`, which is fine.
2. I define template type aliases `variadic1_char`, `variadic2_char`, `variadic1_int`, `variadic2_int`

   ```
   template<class...T>
   using variadic1_char = variadic1 < char, T... > ;
   template<class...T>
   using variadic2_char = variadic2 < char, T... > ;

   template<class...T>
   using variadic1_int = variadic1 < int, T... > ;
   template<class...T>
   using variadic2_int = variadic2 < int, T... > ;
   ```

   Now I can write `applyTo_double_float<variadic1_char>::type` which gives me `variadic1 < char, double,float >`. Likewise
   `applyTo_double_float<variadic1_int>::type` == `variadic1 < int, double,float >`, etc.

My question is if it is possible to reduce twice the number of templates from the stage 2 (4 pieces) and generalize it with the help of 2 template-template-template-s, namely `magicVariadic1`,  `magicVariadic2` to be able to write something like `applyTo_double_float<magicVariadic1<char>>::type` instead of `applyTo_double_float<variadic1_char>::type`.

Or maybe even it's possible to introduce one `superMagic` template which will replace all templates from stage 2 and allow to write e.g `applyTo_double_float<superMagic<variadic1, char>>::type` instead of `applyTo_double_float<variadic1_char>::type` etc.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: As you might have noticed, template template template-parameters are not allowed. They are not necessary either; even template template-parameters aren't strictly required. You can as well use the technique of allocators, which can define a nested "template typedef": `struct my_allocator { template<typename T> struct rebind { using type = some_other_allocator<T>; }; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class...T> 
struct variadic1 {};

template<template<typename...> class Templ>
struct applyTo_double_float
{
    typedef Templ<double, float> type;
};

template<class T1>
struct variadic1_magic
{
   template<class...T> struct inner
   {
      typedef variadic1<T1, T...> type;
   };
};

int main()
{
   typedef applyTo_double_float<variadic1_magic<char>::inner>::type Type1;
   std::cout << typeid(Type1).name() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Update**

A better solution, thanks to @dyp:

```
template<template<class...> class TT, class... U>
struct super_magic
{
   template<class... V>
      struct inner
      {
         using type = TT<U..., V...>;
      };
};

int main()

{
   using Type1 = applyTo_double_float< super_magic<variadic1, char>::inner >::type;
   std::cout << typeid(Type1).name() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you can generalize that via `template<template<class...> class TT, class... U> struct super_magic { template<class... V> struct inner { using type = TT<U..., V...>; }; };`, then `using Type1 = applyTo_double_float< super_magic<variadic1, char>::inner >;`

Comment: It looks like a type closure.. or is there a better name?

Comment: @dyp. Cool, exactly what I need. It can be even little bit simplified `template<template<class...> class TT, class... U> struct super_magic { template<class... V> using type = TT<U..., V...>; };`
That's exactly as you've mentioned that template aliases can be substituted by nested "template typedefs".